# Update many objects, create if not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working with a mean application and one of it functions is to do upload of csv files and convert it to json and persist in a mongodb database. But even month i receive a csv with new records and records that already exists (with new informations or not) in the database. Summing up, **i need to update many objects and create it if not exist**. My question is, what is the better way to do this, because these files are very large.

The current version just create these records like this:

```
Patient.create(records ,function(err, records) {
                if (err){
                    res.send(err);
                    console.log(err);
                }

            res.json(records);
 });
```

Comment: What's the content of `records`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following some simple steps

1. At Node JS use parse CSV to convert CSV into JSON
2. Then take all the data from collection and compare it with the new data.
3. For Comparison of data you can use lodash library, it's method is really fast.
4. Once you got the _id of the data which is new or need to be update. You can use the below query

db.collectionName.update({$in:{"_id":ids}},{$set:{"key":"value"}},{upsert:true, multi:true},function(err,doc){
     console.log(doc)
})

don't forget to add upsert true because you have new data also.

Hope it Help!!

Comment: So, in this case i need to put the update query into a iterator?

Comment: No $in will act like a iterator. You just find out the ids which are new and need to be updated and put this inside an array, let's say ids = ["AREDS2323","ASDS2323"] and pass into that above query